# Dragabble shapes on Buffered Image

Tags: java, shapes

I'm developing a simple shape editor in Java, I was drawing everything on BufferedImage scince I want to save drawn image. The user can draw shapes by choosing shape from the menu and then click on image. I started to implement dragging shapes. When I drag a shape, a path of this shape is being created... I assume it's because I draw on BufferedImage so it's like 'temporary'. Or am I wrong? I was thinking of re-write everything, this time not drawing on BufferedImage, just creating Graphics2D, but I have problems with implementing listeners as I need to transfer my Graphics2D there to add shapes there, also I don't know how to call repaint in for eg. my MouseListener class. I was planning to create BufferedImage when user wants to save image, I would create it with help of vector where I store all shapes (or is it better way?). Here's my Panel class:

```
public class Panel {

    public static Graphics2D img2;

    public static Graphics2D getIm() {
        return this.img2;
    }

    public Panel(JFrame frame) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(true) {

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                super.paintComponent(g);


                img2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();  
                img2.dispose();
            };
        };
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); // setting rendering to achieve better looking shapes
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        MouseListenerShapes mouseListenerShapes = new MouseListenerShapes();
        panel.addMouseListener(mouseListenerShapes);
        //MouseMoveAdapter mouseMouseMoveAdapter = new MouseMoveAdapter();
        //panel.addMouseMotionListener(mouseMouseMoveAdapter);
        //panel.addMouseListener(mouseMouseMoveAdapter);
        frame.add(panel);
    };
}
```

I did a lot of reading but still I can't make it right, I need my shapes to be resizable, movable, etc. but at the same time I want to save image afterwards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I'm going to propose is going to be far from complete, but I hope it will illustrate some concepts that should help you find success. I'm going to build a panel with two movable images, but will do so using patterns that should make this code easier to maintain.

I highly recommend separating your rendering layer (your `JComponents`) and your model layer (the shapes and their locations) into distinct objects. This is referred to as *separation of concerns* and will make your life easier in the long run.

First lets define one of your shapes that appears in the screen. I'm going to keep mine very simple and create one with location, size, and a `BufferedImage`:

```
class DrawNode
{
    private Rectangle bounds;
    private BufferedImage image;

    public DrawNode()
    {
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return bounds;
    }

    public void setBounds( Rectangle bounds )
    {
        this.bounds = bounds;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage()
    {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage( BufferedImage image )
    {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Next, let's create a model for holding the collection of your shapes. One neat thing we can do with the model is have it accept a listener that will get invoked whenever parts of our 2D space become "invalidated." Parts of the space can become invalid and will need repainting if a node was in a given area previously and has been moved to a new area. We'll also include some helper methods for determining what shape occupies a given space, etc. These helpers can be greatly optimized in terms of their efficiency, but my simple version will use brute-force iteration:

```
class DrawPanelModel
{
    private final List<DrawNode> nodes;
    private final Consumer<Rectangle> invalidAreaListener;

    public DrawPanelModel( Consumer<Rectangle> invalidAreaListener )
    {
        this.invalidAreaListener = invalidAreaListener;
        nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNode( DrawNode node )
    {
        nodes.add( node );
    }

    public Optional<DrawNode> getNodeForPoint( Point p )
    {
        return nodes.stream()
                .filter( node -> node.getBounds().contains( p ))
                .findFirst();
    }

    public Stream<DrawNode> getNodesInRectangle( Rectangle r )
    {
        return nodes.stream()
                .filter( node -> node.getBounds().intersects( r ));
    }

    public void setNodeLocation( DrawNode node, Point p )
    {
        Rectangle bounds = (Rectangle)node.getBounds().clone();
        bounds.setLocation( p );
        setNodeBounds( node, bounds );
    }

    public void setNodeBounds( DrawNode node, Rectangle bounds )
    {
        Rectangle old = node.getBounds();
        node.setBounds( Objects.requireNonNull( bounds ));

        if ( old == null || !old.equals( bounds ))
        {
            invalidAreaListener.accept( bounds );

            if ( old != null ) {
                invalidAreaListener.accept( old );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next we need a way to render our shapes/nodes to the screen. We could draw each node every time we call `paint(...)`, but that's not very efficient since we only really need to re-draw the invalid areas. We can leave the rest of the areas alone by making sure the `JComponent` utilizes double-buffering:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDoubleBuffered(boolean)

**Edit:** Slight correction: double buffering will provide benefits mainly when it comes to scrolling if you were to place the component in a scroll pane. I don't think it will affect the behavior of simple repaint events. (Was tired when I wrote this yesterday)

One common technique used to accomplish this in Swing is to use a `CellRendererPane` in conjunction with a `JLabel` that you use as a renderer. Whenever we need to paint a node in a specific location, we can assign the desired image and size to the `JLabel` and have the `CellRendererPane` render that `JLabel` during the paint procedure (potentially more than once) in different locations.

Let's create such a `JLabel` subclass and give it a helper method to initialize its state form a given node:

```
class ShapeRenderer extends JLabel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ShapeRenderer() {
    }

    public void initFrom( DrawNode node )
    {
        setIcon( new ImageIcon( node.getImage() ));
        setSize( node.getBounds().getSize() );
    }

    // Methods below are overridden as a performance optimization:
    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void revalidate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void repaint( long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height ) {
    }

    @Override
    public void repaint( Rectangle r ) {
    }

    @Override
    public void repaint() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void firePropertyChange( String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue ) {
    }

    @Override
    public void firePropertyChange( String propertyName, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue ) {
    }
}
```

At this point we have the `JComponent` left, let's create a custom one. We'll give it a `DrawPanelModel`, `CellRendererPane`, and our `ShapeRenderer`. It's going to subscribe to the model as a listener, calling `repaint(Rectangle)` in response to the model invalidating in area whenever a node moves. Keep in mind that `repaint(...)` does **not** paint immediately, but rather schedules a paint event to occur at a future point in time. What this implies is that we can actually move several nodes and the Swing framework will provide us with one paint event that will have the union of all of our invalid rectangles specified as the `Graphic's` clip area. But, our code doesn't really care whether the invalid areas are combined or not. If the framework decides to give us a paint event for each of the areas we invalidate, we can handle that as well:

```
class DrawPanel extends JComponent
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final CellRendererPane renderPane;
    private final ShapeRenderer renderer;
    private final DrawPanelModel model;

    public DrawPanel()
    {
        renderPane = new CellRendererPane();
        add( renderPane );
        setDoubleBuffered( true );
        renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        model = new DrawPanelModel( this::repaint );

        DrawMouseListener listener = new DrawMouseListener();
        addMouseListener( listener );
        addMouseMotionListener( listener );
    }

    public void addNode( BufferedImage image, Point loc )
    {
        DrawNode node = new DrawNode();
        node.setImage( image );
        model.addNode( node );
        model.setNodeBounds( node, new Rectangle( loc, new Dimension( image.getWidth(), image.getHeight() )));
    }

    @Override
    public void doLayout()
    {
        renderPane.setSize( getSize() );
    }

    private void paintBackground( Graphics2D g )
    {
        g.setColor( Color.WHITE );
        g.fill( g.getClip() );
    }

    private void paintNodes( Graphics2D g )
    {
        model.getNodesInRectangle( g.getClipBounds() )
            .forEach( node -> paintNode( node, g ));
    }

    private void paintNode( DrawNode node, Graphics2D g )
    {
        Rectangle r = node.getBounds();
        renderer.initFrom( node );
        renderPane.paintComponent( g, renderer, this, r );
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent( Graphics aG )
    {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)aG.create();
        paintBackground( g );
        paintNodes( g );
    }

    class DrawMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        private Optional<DrawNode> movingNode;

        public DrawMouseListener()
        {
            movingNode = Optional.empty();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e )
        {
            movingNode = model.getNodeForPoint( e.getPoint() );
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e )
        {
            movingNode = Optional.empty();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e )
        {
            movingNode.ifPresent( node -> {
                model.setNodeLocation( node, e.getPoint() );
            } );
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, a manual test:

```
@Test
public void testPanel() throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {

        // Create frame:
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 1 ));

        // Create draw panel:
        DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        frame.add( drawPanel );

        // Show frame:
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize( new Dimension( 1000, 600 ));
        frame.setVisible( true );

        // Create first image:
        BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage( 50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        Graphics2D g = image1.createGraphics();
        g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
        g.fillOval( 0, 0, 50, 50 );

        // Add first image to draw panel:
        drawPanel.addNode( image1, new Point( 100, 100 ));

        // Create second image:
        BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage( 50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        Graphics2D g2 = image2.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor( Color.RED );
        g2.fillOval( 0, 0, 50, 50 );

        // Add second image to draw panel:
        drawPanel.addNode( image2, new Point( 200, 100 ));
    } );

    Thread.sleep( Long.MAX_VALUE );
}
```

Results:

[image]